# Replacing HTML tooltip content with PHP/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, tooltip

So, I have that WordPress website on which I installed a template (Zoo). My problem is that I want the whole site to be in French, and there are three buttons in that template which `title` tag is coded deep in a js file that is inside a plugin which has been integrated to the template.

These are my first steps as a web developer (I come from C++) and I'm having quite a hard time understanding what is missing in the files, but I understood a few things by looking around.

So I made a child theme. This is the functions.php file. I think it works fine, but here it is in case I am doing it wrong :

```
<?php
function removethosedamntooltips(){
    wp_register_script('removetooltips', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/removetooltips.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'removetooltips' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'removethosedamntooltips');
```

This is the aforementioned removetooltips.js file. I believe I have to call for a button hover because the template is single-page parallax and the buttons I want to modify are not visible until you click another button which allows for another display without sending the browser to another URL (if I remove line 2 and the closing brackets that go with it, it doesn't work anyway). Also, those tooltips appear only on mouse hover, so it seems a good idea :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  alert("jQuery!!");
  jQuery("button").hover(function(){
    alert("jQuery!!");
    jQuery(".mfp-arrow-left").attr("title", "Précédent (flèche gauche)");
    jQuery(".mfp-arrow-right").attr("title", "Suivant (flèche droite)");
    jQuery(".mfp-close").attr("title", "Fermer (Esc)");
  });
});
```

The first alert displays after the page is loaded, but the second one does not show up. The tooltips (button title) still show up in English.

A piece of information that might be useful to solve this problem (I'm only 2 days into reading stuff about JavaScript and jQuery so I don't really know): I had to use `jQuery` instead of `$` or the console would tell me that `$` is an unknown function. Do I need to somehow include the jQuery framework in my file (if so, where and how ?), although a calling for the jQuery library already shows up in the header ?

If you provide a solution that will remove the tooltips instead of replacing their content, I will be happy enough.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: The second `alert()` doesn't display when you hover over the button? Have you tried to `.unbind()` the hover event before adding your own? Something like...`jQuery('button').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(function() { ...`

Comment: `unbind()` did not work; I think it's because the tooltip is not created as a tooltip but comes from the `title` attribute in the HTML code.
Can one stack methods in the same line like you did ?
Also, I noticed you use apostrophes while I use quotation marks. Do both work the same ?

Comment: Yes, [you can chain jQuery methods](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/#chaining). Single vs. double quotes doesn't matter in JavaScript, as long as you're consistent, and escape when necessary.

Comment: in wordpress is enough to add `"jquery"` as the handle of third parameter of the [wp_register_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) in order to enqueue jQuery .. no need to include it again. ( follow the above  link ). and yes, jQuery in wordpress is run with [noConflict](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) wrappers, so `jQuery` and not `$` is the way .

Comment: I can help you with to use the `$` instead of `jQuery`. Wrap your code in: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { })`. The `$` parameter will be the accepted alias for `jQuery` inside the function wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 
`jQuery("button").hover(function(){...});`
You should find the container in which all buttons are placed or just use `body`
and use jquery `.on()` method. As far as I know it'll work.
so your complete code will be like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  alert("jQuery!!");
  jQuery("body").on("hover", "button", function(){
    jQuery(".mfp-arrow-left").attr("title", "Précédent (flèche gauche)");
    jQuery(".mfp-arrow-right").attr("title", "Suivant (flèche droite)");
    jQuery(".mfp-close").attr("title", "Fermer (Esc)");
  });
});
```

**Explanation:**
Using `.on()` method binds the event with dynamically created elements too. As you mentioned in your question that buttons are not created until another button/link is clicked.

**Edit:** Tested this one and its working. I've removed the second alert because with that you won't be able to test.

Comment: This did not work as is. The second alert does not show up so it doesn't trigger. I thought "does the button have to be a direct child of the selected element ?" but I tried that too and it does not work either.

Comment: No. I forgot to clear `.hover(function(){..})` after the selectors. 
with `.on()` the function is passed as an argument.